# Failed to execute git - VS Code?

Tags: git, macos, visual-studio-code

Why does my Visual Studio Code keep popping up this message?

I don't even use Git, and it started happening. Is it because I opened the Git panel?

Restarting does nothing, changing the settings/config doesn't help either. Super annoying and frustrated, please help.

[image]

Comment: Which OS? You should provide more info.

Comment: Oh sorry didn't think of that. I'm on Mac OS 10.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think VS Code assumes you already have Git installed from another mean,

- Xcode
- GitHub Desktop
- Homebrew
- [Git](https://git-scm.com/download/mac)

Thus, it directly attempts to locate Git and fails.

I will recommend you report this to VS Code project at GitHub, but installing Git is a quick workaround.

Comment: Ah makes sense! Yeah I will report this and will install Git. Thanks!

Comment: Just as a follow up see my comment below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376087/failed-to-execute-git-vs-code/35100852#comment57927597_35100852

Answer (score 2):

Install git on your machine so it will be found in your path.

Once it's there, VC should not alert you anymore.

https://git-scm.com/downloads

Comment: I think it is more common to call VS Code or Code. VC has been used for Visual C++ for years.

Answer (score 0):

On OSX, assuming you have XCode installed, you will need to run `git` once from shell in order to agree to licensing terms. Otherwise Code will fail to run it.

Comment: I actually reported this on their github issues and its something they needed to fix. https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1508

Answer (score 0):

Open windows command prompt or the command prompt of git in Visual Studio code by using short key `ctrl+shift+c` and then enter the this command:
`git config --global user.email "youremailid@example.com"`

After this now stage your changes and then try to commit!